# Projection of a vector over a set

Tags: optimization, projection

> If $D$ is a set, so that $D = \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid Ax = a \right\} \neq \emptyset$ with $A \in \mathbb{R}^{l\times n}$ with rank $l$, and $a \in \mathbb{R}^l$. If $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then, find the projection of $y$ in $D$.

---

My thoughts are that this is equivalent to solve the problem: $$\min \quad \|x-y\| \quad \text{s.t} \quad Ax=a$$ but I don't know how to proceed from there.

Answer (score 0):

Since the rank of $A$ is $l$ then $n \ge l$.   We need to solve the system

$ A x = a $

The solution is $ x = X_0 + V u $, where $V \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times (n-l)} $ and $ u \in \mathbb{R}^l $

Now you want to find $x$ such that $\| y - x \|$ is minimum.  For that, we have

$\| y - x \|^2 = (x - y)^T (x - y) = (X_0 - y + V u)^T (X_0 - y + V u) $

The minimum of this function occurs at

$ u = - (V^T V)^{-1} V^T (X_0 - y) $

Hence the projection is

$ x = X_0 + V u = X_0 - V (V^T V)^{-1} V^T (X_0 - y) $

Alternatively, we can use Lagrange multipliers, to minimize the Lagrange function

$f(x, \lambda) = (x - y)^T (x - y) + \lambda^T (A x - a ) $

where $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^l $.  Taking the gradient with respect to $x$ and $\lambda$,

$\nabla_x f = 2(x - y) + A^T \lambda $

$\nabla_{\lambda} f = A x - a $

From the first of these two,

$ x = y - \dfrac{1}{2} A^T \lambda $

which upon substituting into the second, yields

$ A y - \dfrac{1}{2} A A^T \lambda - a = 0 $

Solving for \lambda,

$\lambda = 2 (A A^T)^{-1} (A y - a ) $

And finally, substituting this,

$ x = y - A^T (A A^T)^{-1} A y + A^T (A A^T)^{-1} a $

which reduces to

$ x = (I - A^T (A A^T)^{-1} A) y + A^T (A A^T)^{-1} a $

which is an alternative and better form for the projection.

Comment: thankyou very much, this helps me a lot, i'll write it in terms of A and $A^T$

Comment: @IanBollschweilerVargas  I've updated my solution to express the projection in terms of $A$ and $A^T$.